# backgroundworker vb.net cancel async function

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

im running a backgroundworker which is calling a function to download huge files and folders. im not able to stop this through cancelasync. The cancelationpending event is received, but my function still calculates.
How can I stop the thread?

```
Private Sub copydownloads_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles copydownloads.DoWork  
DirectoryCopy()
End Sub

    public sub DirectoryCopy()
    'here is the work done
    end sub
```

Comment: Show at least *some* evidence that you are checking the CancellationPending property.  If you have none so show then you already know why it isn't stopping.

Answer (score 2):

CancelAsync wont magically stop BackgroundWorker. You have to manually poll CancelPending property in your download code.

*The worker code should periodically check the CancellationPending property to see if it has been set to true.*

When you see that CancellationPending is set to true, you have to stop your downloading (ie. download small chunks in a loop and check flag constantly).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

See this question for an example code how to download file in chunks. Add CancelPending checking inside that code:
[Download File With Start / Pause / Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898847/download-file-with-start-pause-stop)

Comment: thanks and solved
never assumed that is so easy.

public sub DirectoryCopy
  If copydownloads.CancellationPending = True Then
                                Exit Sub
  End If
end sub